# Appending items into php list

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to retrieve the user ID of the retweeters of certain tweets of a user in twitter.
The tweet IDs are retrieved in an array using API.

```
$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken,    $accesstokensecret);
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&screen_name=BillGates");
$i=0;
foreach ($tweets as $trend)
 {
  $array[$i]=$trend->id_str;
  $i=$i+1;
 }
```

I would like to add the retweeters ID into a single array.The return type of API is in a list form.How is a list appended to itself with user id of the retweeters using api

```
foreach ($tweets as $trend)
 {
  $array[$i]=$trend->id_str;
  $users = $connection->get("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets/:array[i].format");
    foreach($users as $u)
    {
     $userlist[j]=$u;
     $j=$j+1;
    }

    $i=$i+1;

}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I found  the problem with inserting user id into userlist[] array,I doubt wheather the problem is with php syntax.somehow i do note get the expected values in array even in a single value.Here is what i used


        $url ="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweeters/ids.json?id=",$array[5]"&count=100&stringify_ids=true";
        echo $url;
 $user = $connection->get($url);
 $users =json_encode($user);